# Get User IP in Flask - Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: nginx, flask, proxy, ip, gunicorn

I'm trying to get the user IP inside my flask application. The problem is that I keep on getting either the localhost IP, or the IP of the server that the server is hosted on, and not my actual IP.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
if request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For"):
        client_ip = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")[0]
    else:
        client_ip = request.remote_addr
```

I have also attempted to use proxyfix, but I still have the same issue.

Below is my nginx configuration file:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass ......;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            proxy_send_timeout 300; 
    }

    # Error pages
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }
    
        # Deny access to hidden files and directories
        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }
}
```

Does anyone know any possible solution? I have tried everything mentioned in all the other stackoverflow questions but nothing has worked for me.

Comment: I am also using a load balancer.